# How to access console logs of flutter app packaged as msix?

Tags: windows, flutter, windows-11, msix, flutter-windows

## Background

I used [msix flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/msix) to package my app. It installs without any problems but immediately fails after starting it on Windows 11 (on Windows 10 everything works fine) without any error message.

## Problem

I am therefore trying to get a hold of the console logs of the app (= print() method) but cannot find a way to do so. I guess the msix app container virtualisation stands in my way.

I already tried setting the `execution_alias` and starting the app from PowerShell. Still no logs are shown.

Any help on how to access console logs of a msix app is much appreciated.